# How do I configure Openfire to use custom database using openfire.xml?

Tags: properties, xmpp, openfire

I tried out [this guide](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/database.html) from the Openfire documentation but none of my changes seem to have been applied. I can't login as any of the user from my custom database even if I set user names as admin. Do I need to manually apply all the changes to the system properties stored in the database (Openfire's `ofProperty` table)?

I'd also like to know if there's a way to prevent or customize which tables Openfire will add to my database.

Comment: Are you able to make this work? I just saw I have my answer for this way back '11

Comment: Yeah, I think. Sorry I forgot to respond to this but I can't remember how I got it working. The feature has long been forgotten.

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I've always made it a point to accept answers that solve my issues, so it probably didn't.

Comment: @PsychoPunch any solution ?? i am facing similar issues

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I did to setup external database (in my case MySQL):

Assuming that you have a running Openfire instance, you should stop the server and edit the openfire.xml

Just add `<setup>false</setup>` so next time you open the web interface you will be directed to the setup page which will allow you to select and setup your database server.

From Openfire install directory copy the SQL query from /resources/database (choose the one for your specific database, in my case I used `openfire_mysql.sql`)

Of course you need to setup privileges.

From there I just followed the wizard and put the information in the input fields when setting up the database, like IP address, username and password that I have setup in the privileges in phpMyAdmin. Everything should be up and running within minutes.

In case you get error when setting up the database from the web interface, try to check if your database server MySQL port is open, its 3306. Do some `sudo iptables` if its not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @psycho-punch did this helped?

Comment: @xybrek can you help me with the similar issue?

Comment: @Newbiee what issue?

Comment: @xybrek can you guide me how to integrate openfire with my own database, i mean instead of making entry to ofUser table i want to make it in My own USERS table. i followed the i tried following **https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/3.5.0_rc1/documentation/db-integration-guide.html** link but its not helping

Comment: @xybrek I do have already running openfire server but now i want to make changes in database connection string as i am going to deploy code on live server and i really don't want to re-setup opnefire again.