# Property 'provider.user.className' as specified in openfire.xml differs from what is stored in the database

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

I am configuring openfire.xml for custom database integration and following is my openfire.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
    This file stores bootstrap properties needed by Openfire.
    Property names must be in the format: "prop.name.is.blah=value"
    That will be stored as:
        <prop>
            <name>
                <is>
                    <blah>value</blah>
                </is>
            </name>
        </prop>

    Most properties are stored in the Openfire database. A
    property viewer and editor is included in the admin console.
-->
<!-- root element, all properties must be under this element -->
<jive> 
  <adminConsole> 
    <!-- Disable either port by setting the value to -1 -->  
    <port>9090</port>  
    <securePort>9091</securePort> 
  </adminConsole>  
  <locale>en</locale>  
  <!-- Network settings. By default, Openfire will bind to all network interfaces.
      Alternatively, you can specify a specific network interfaces that the server
      will listen on. For example, 127.0.0.1. This setting is generally only useful
       on multi-homed servers. -->  
  <!--
    <network>
        <interface></interface>
    </network>
    -->  
  <connectionProvider> 
    <className>org.jivesoftware.database.DefaultConnectionProvider</className> 
  </connectionProvider>  
  <database> 
    <defaultProvider> 
      <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>  
      <serverURL>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/openfire?rewriteBatchedStatements=true</serverURL>  
      <username>root</username>  
      <password>123</password>  
      <testSQL>select 1</testSQL>  
      <testBeforeUse>false</testBeforeUse>  
      <testAfterUse>false</testAfterUse>  
      <minConnections>5</minConnections>  
      <maxConnections>25</maxConnections>  
      <connectionTimeout>1.0</connectionTimeout> 
    </defaultProvider> 
  </database>  
  <setup>true</setup>  
  <jdbcProvider> 
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>  
    <connectionString>jdbc:mysql://localhost/openfire?user=root&amp;password=123</connectionString> 
  </jdbcProvider>  
  <provider> 
    <auth> 
      <className>org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.JDBCAuthProvider</className> 
    </auth>  
    <user> 
      <className>org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.JDBCUserProvider</className> 
    </user> 
  </provider>  
  <jdbcAuthProvider> 
    <passwordSQL>SELECT password FROM user WHERE username=?</passwordSQL>  
    <passwordType>sha256</passwordType> 
  </jdbcAuthProvider>  
  <jdbcUserProvider> 
    <loadUserSQL>SELECT name,email_address FROM user WHERE username=?</loadUserSQL>  
    <userCountSQL>SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user</userCountSQL>  
    <allUsersSQL>SELECT username FROM user</allUsersSQL>  
    <searchSQL>SELECT username FROM user WHERE</searchSQL>  
    <usernameField>username</usernameField>  
    <nameField>name</nameField>  
    <emailField>email</emailField> 
  </jdbcUserProvider> 
</jive>
```

there are no errors in **errors.log** but I see this line in **warn.log** file

```
2014.04.09 09:24:18 org.jivesoftware.util.JiveGlobals - Property 'provider.user.className' as specified in openfire.xml differs from what is stored in the database.  Please make property changes in the database instead of openfire.xml.
```

I am modifying the openfire.xml by looking [this](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/db-integration-guide.html) but still a warning.Can any body please tell me what mistake I am doing?

Comment: Have you seen this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122019/how-do-i-configure-openfire-to-use-custom-database-using-openfire-xml/7240897#7240897

Comment: @xybrek yes.I have already setup my database.what do to next?

Comment: @JqueryLearner are you sure that property are same as that u have specified into the Database? and When u have Specified the properties check all the properties with database again.

Comment: @Krishna where will I get database properties?

Comment: @JqueryLearner Means whatever Database that u have configured that Name and Spell are same? for ex provider.user.className or Database names check all the spell bro.

Comment: @JqueryLearner i am working on that okey i will let u know :)

Comment: @Krishna sorry for late response actually my TL was here.As you know we can talk here in stackoverflow so can we can talk in gmail please.

Comment: @JqueryLearner Sure i have given gmail in my profile u can just add me i will net u know.

Comment: @Krishna I can not see your gmail in your profile

Comment: @JqueryLearner kishan.bheemajiyani@gmail.com here we go. will talk with u after my office hours. :)

Comment: @Krishna I have just sent you a test mail.Please add me in your contact.Also I am waiting for the solution for this question

Comment: @JqueryLearner i did i have small solution but m not sure that will work or not. login into your openfire console and there is System Properties. click on that there is list of properties and try to add your property there. and restart it. and see wether its working or not.

Comment: i cant check it bcoz i am not having rights in my office computer. :(

Comment: @Krishna I will just try as you said

Comment: @JqueryLearner i got an Example for that look this http://blog.csdn.net/tt2sdz/article/details/5484474 where they specify that properties is 'provider.auth.className' not 'provider.user.className' try to change it and see its working or not

Comment: @Krishna yes you are right.when I check in openfire provider.auth.className is org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.DefaultAuthProvider now by making both same it solved

Comment: @Krishna you can post as answer and I will accept

Comment: @JqueryLearner Sure dude i will put it :) and ya i am glad that i could help. :)

Comment: @Krishna Can i see the user details in openfire?Is it possible?

Comment: @JqueryLearner Which user admin users of Simple user that u are registering.??

Comment: @Krishna sorry I did not understand

Comment: @JqueryLearner Which user u want to see? i mean user that are registered in openfire?

Comment: @Krishna I have some users in my mysqlDb.Users have email,username,password etc.So can I get the details(for example email ) using openfire

Comment: @JqueryLearner Well i dont have that actual idea but login into the open fire console and see users and if u dont get that users u need to create them by java Program. and then u can see them. :) +1 for great question ;)

Comment: @Krishna so have you done like this earlier?

Comment: @JqueryLearner well i have done it :) but not for project but for learning purpose. i dont have that much experience bro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is Some Mistake While authenticating Database.

[See this block](http://blog.csdn.net/tt2sdz/article/details/5484474)

where the properties name convention is differ its  `'provider.auth.className'`  and not `'provider.user.className'`
try that and i am sure that will help and other way is even u can login to your openfire and just system properties u can add your manual properties. :) try that i am sure that will help

Comment: I am facing problem in smack

Comment: Which Problem? Can u explain it?

Comment: M not having access there. admin have to provide me that i given request.